# How to choose an account to deploy a contract in truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-config

How do you select an account to deploy a contract using:
1)Metamask
2)Parity
3)some config file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out.
in `truffle.js` you can specify `from:` field like this:

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // Match any network id
      from: '0xA21983B35C767CF8609D95F4886C9A18A194D8AA'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's the public address, but how does truffle knows the associated private key?

Comment: @David天宇Wong it doesn't need to know, your geth/parity node doesn't even know it. You have to `unlock` your key

Comment: It needs to know it to sign transactions coming from this address. If you deploy a contract you need to sign the transaction deploying that contract.